# Zurb-foundation: Require a checkbox

Tags: zurb-foundation

Todays [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) (zf) question is about checkboxes:

**how can i require a checkbox, in my case for accepting our policy?**
If the checkbox is not ticked it has to show a standard foundation error.

I know there is already a patch for this made by [huchenme](https://github.com/huchenme/foundation/commit/c15676c7ab9176404bdeddf0f87cc4aab142d382) on GitHub, but it is not incorporated yet, and i'd like to know if there is any way around modifying and minifying the zf source?

I am aware of the possibility to define my own validation pattern for text boxes, but this does not work for checkboxes.

I'd like to do it with zfs own tools, i could just hack together some JS stuff, but is there a more elegant way to do it by using zfs tools?

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Right now, I'm using custom Javascript and the .error class.

Comment: itsn it possible in HTML5 at least to add the "required" tag to the input element ?  its more browser notification but it will be a quick workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript for this, you could have the form have a trigger to your JS function.

```
onsubmit="return checkForm()"
```

The function would consist something like :

```
function checkForm(){
  if(!document.getElementById('checkboxID').checked){
    document.getElementById('termsAndConditionsError').show();
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
   return true;
  }
}
```

Some playing around with this will handle it for you.